# How can I determine whether an individual comment can be removed by the logged-in user?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

The stream table contains a comments array - a sampling of the comments, which in turn, has a can_remove field. This field is either true or false depending on whether the currently logged-in user can remove comments for that particular stream post, according to the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

The problem is that the can_remove field applies to ALL the comments. This is not the correct behavior. Certain comments within the comment_list may be removable by the user while others may not be removable.

For example, if I comment on my friend's post, I should be able to remove my comment. However, I should not be able to remove other people's comments on that post. I don't understand how the value of the can_remove field is determined in a case like this. It certainly cannot be applied to every comment because I should not be allowed to remove every comment, yet there is only one can_remove field per comments object per stream post.

The correct behavior would be for every comment within the comment_list to have its own can_remove field.